# Are algebraic maps from the n-dimensional torus to the special unitary group of large enough degree null-homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $S^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the unit sphere, and $T^n=(S^1)^n$ the $n$-torus.
Loday proved in [1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0073720) that every algebraic map $T^n\to S^n$ is null-homotopic.
In particular, since $SU(2)\simeq S^3$, every algebraic map $T^3\to SU(2)$ is null-homotopic.

What can be said more generally about algebraic maps from $T^n$ to $SU(k)$, maybe assuming $k$ is large enough?

Has this been investigated in any way? Why is K-theory involved in Loday's proof and should I look into it if I want to have a go at this question?

[[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0073720) Jean-Louis Loday. *Applications algébriques du tore dans la sphère et de Sp×Sq dans Sp+q*.

Comment: What do you mean by an algebraic map $T^n \to SU(k)$?

Comment: Considering $T^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $SU(k)\subset \mathbb{R}^{2k^2}$, a map $T^n\to SU(k)$ is algebraic if it is the restriction of a polynomial map $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to  \mathbb{R}^{2k^2}$.  I don't know if that's standard but I think it is what Loday means.